# Jolt json transform question. Have a record with an array inside and need to convert to an array of records

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I need to transform some flow files in NIFI and would like to use Jolt transforms. I have been playing with this for a while and cannot figure out a transform that will work. I have...

```
{
  "asset": "transformer1",
  "readings": {
    "oil_temp": 0.7499248991503604,
    "otc_top_temp": 0.2870503485615279
  },
  "timestamp": "02/17/2020 19:07:31",
  "key": "e2af07ab-4d21-4a70-ba3f-9113bb335d1e"
}
```

and need to transform that into an array of records like this...

```
[
  {
    "tag": "transformer1.oil_temp",
    "timestamp": "02/17/2020 19:07:31",
    "value": 0.7499248991503604
  },
  {
    "tag": "transformer1.otc_top_temp",
    "timestamp": "02/17/2020 19:07:31",
    "value": 0.2870503485615279
  }
]
```

I hope that this is possible. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: From the jolt docs ... "Currently, all the Stock transforms just effect the "structure" of the data. To do data manipulation, you will need to write Java code.".   This has been a blocker for some puzzles like yours ... you need the value of "tag" to be the concatenation of  the value of "asset", a period and the name of elements south of readings.  This smells like data manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with multiple transform steps:

1. Readings map to list
2. Create new tag field by using concat operation
3. Pass through only values you want as a result

JoltSpec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "readings": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,asset)": "[#2].asset",
          "$": "[#2].name",
          "@": "[#2].value",
          "@(2,timestamp)": "[#2].timestamp"
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "tag": "=concat(@(1,asset),'.',@(1,name))"
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "tag": "[&1].tag",
        "timestamp": "[&1].timestamp",
        "value": "[&1].value"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Input:

```
{
  "asset": "transformer1",
  "readings": {
    "oil_temp": 0.7499248991503604,
    "otc_top_temp": 0.2870503485615279
  },
  "timestamp": "02/17/2020 19:07:31",
  "key": "e2af07ab-4d21-4a70-ba3f-9113bb335d1e"
}
```

Output:

```
[ {
  "tag" : "transformer1.oil_temp",
  "timestamp" : "02/17/2020 19:07:31",
  "value" : 0.7499248991503604
}, {
  "tag" : "transformer1.otc_top_temp",
  "timestamp" : "02/17/2020 19:07:31",
  "value" : 0.2870503485615279
} ]
```

Test it here: https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception